# Is application/json-p text/json-p already implementable?

Tags: javascript, web-services, json, jsonp

I've read http://www.json-p.org/ which states a safer and stricter subset of JSON-P.

> The most critical piece of this proposal is that browser vendors must
>   begin to enforce this rule for script
>   tags that are receiving JSON-P
>   content, and throw errors (or at least
>   stop processing) on any non-conforming
>   JSON-P content.

My question is Is that subset of JSON-P already implementable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no current way to implement/enforce what is proposed, as changes to how browsers process the `script` tag are required.  If you really wanted to implement the proposal, you could build a proxy service on your server which does the JSONP verification for you.

The only real problem this proposal is trying to solve is to make JSONP requests more secure for consumers of JSONP enabled services.  However, I honestly think this security problem is a non-issue.

As long as web service consumers are using trusted JSONP services, there is no JSONP specific security threat.  If you think the service you are consuming might be untrustworthy, simply don't use it.  You can find an alternative service or proxy the untrustworthy service through your own server to clean/verify the response.

The same vulnerabilities which exist for JSONP also exist for ordinary `script` tags.  People link to third party JavaScript libraries all the time with few issues.  As an example, people everywhere use Google's copy of [jQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js).  Google could easily poison this file and fish user data from any webpage which uses this library.

The moral of the story: **Only use APIs/services you trust**